# How do I recognize fast-forward and rewind gestures for an audio player?

Tags: tvos, siri-remote

I'm developing a tvOS application with an audio player, and I need to support fast-forward and rewind using the same gestures as Apple Music and other audio apps. Specifically, to fast-forward, the user presses and holds on the right side of the remote control's touch surface, and to rewind, the user presses and holds on the left side.

I'm creating two `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` instances, one for fast-forward and one for rewind, and adding them to the view controller's top-level view. For the fast-forward gesture recognizer, I'm setting `allowedPressTypes` to `@[UIPressTypeRightArrow]`, and for the rewind recognizer, I'm setting `allowedPressTypes` to `@[UIPressTypeLeftArrow]`. But these gestures have no effect.

Can anyone provide sample code that implements these gestures properly?

Answer (score 0):

Don't set those allowedPressTypes and it will work.  You'll have to determine where the user tapped in your handler, but the gestures will register.